# In the Xcode debugger, is it possible to do "run to current line"?

Tags: xcode, gdb, debugging

In Xcode, there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to do this.  Visual Studio's debugger provides a keyboard shortcut which sets a temporary breakpoint on the line selected in the code window, runs the debugger to that point, and then removes the breakpoint.  In Xcode, it seems that you have to manually set and remove the breakpoint to accomplish the same thing.

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Right-click on breakpoint border` => `Continue to Here`

Comment: Wow, I never noticed that!  Do you know of any way to bind it to a key sequence?

Comment: I think the best you can do is three key presses: Cmd-\ , Opt-Cmd-P , Cmd-\